# aerospike python not works under centos 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, aerospike

What i have

- running aerospike, test sql go okay
- installed client lib on same machine via pip3 install aerospike
- python version default for centos 7

  ```
          Python 3.4.9
  ```
- Sample for this page is not working

  ```
         https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/index.html
  ```

After i removed try/except block, i get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/aerospike.py", line 4, in <module>
    import aerospike
  File "/tmp/aerospike.py", line 12, in <module>
    client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

I not see source code of connector(cpython used?) and have no any clue where to go from this point.

```
pip3 list
Package                Version 
---------------------- --------
aerospike              3.5.0   
asn1crypto             0.24.0  
atomicwrites           1.2.1   
attrs                  18.2.0  
cassandra-driver       3.15.1  
cffi                   1.11.5  
cryptography           2.3.1   
diff-match-patch       20121119
Django                 2.0.9   
django-chunked-upload  1.1.3   
django-compat          1.0.15  
django-crispy-forms    1.7.2   
django-datatable-view  0.9.0   
django-datatables-view 1.17.0  
django-hijack          2.1.10  
django-import-export   1.1.0   
django-queryset-csv    1.0.1   
django-simple-menu     1.2.1   
django-tables2         2.0.2   
django-tracking2       0.4.1   
et-xmlfile             1.0.1   
future                 0.17.1  
GeoIP                  1.3.2   
idna                   2.7     
importlib-metadata     0.6     
jdcal                  1.4     
more-itertools         4.3.0   
mysqlclient            1.3.13  
odfpy                  1.3.6   
openpyxl               2.5.9   
path.py                11.5.0  
pathlib2               2.3.2   
pidfile                0.1.1   
pika                   0.12.0  
pip                    18.1    
pluggy                 0.8.0   
py                     1.7.0   
pycall                 2.3.2   
pycparser              2.19    
PyMySQL                0.9.2   
pytest                 4.0.1   
python-dateutil        2.7.5   
python-http-client     3.1.0   
pytz                   2018.7  
PyYAML                 3.13    
scandir                1.9.0   
sendgrid               5.6.0   
setuptools             19.6.2  
six                    1.11.0  
tablib                 0.12.1  
unicodecsv             0.14.1  
xlrd                   1.1.0   
xlwt                   1.3.0
```

Comment: Please show your `pip list` and the actual code snippet you're trying. You want to try the code in the doc? https://aerospike-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html

Comment: I have tried exact code from page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a namespace collision. The Aerospike client module is called `aerospike`. Your local script is called `aerospike.py`. The way imports work is that Python will first look locally, then in repos like pip.  Locally it sees your script, and tries to load it again.

Try to rename the script to `aerospike-test.py`

Comment: ops. yes, not thinked about that. but now i have other error. ImportError: bad magic number in 'aerospike': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Comment: This question got answered. Open a different one with a code sample and clear error code in the question, not in a comment to answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Other error was due to aerospike.pyc in same dir.

Comment: Oh yeah. Good find!